# how to adjust Pdf with tabular form with itextSharp in asp.net 3.5

Tags: itext, asp.net-3.5

i 'm working with export details from database to PDF using iTextSharp library. here i just want to result as below:

```
Parent Table
Enquiry Details
...........

   IF(Enquiry Have Reply)
   Create First Child Table
   ..............
   ..............
      If(Reply have File)
      Create Second Child Table
       ..........
       ..........
```

**--------------------------------------------------------Updated-------------------------------------------------------------**

Report returned with Nested Table scenario. Here is my code:

```
protected void lbut_print1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT Person_name,Company_name, Address, City_name," +
                         "(SELECT [Country_name] FROM [FileSystem].[dbo].[tbl_countries] WHERE (Id = Country_id)) AS CountryName," +
                         "(SELECT [state_name] FROM [FileSystem].[dbo].[tbl_states] WHERE (Id = State_id)) AS StateName, Mobile_no, Phone_no, Email_address, Requirement_text, Reference_text, " +
                         "Remarks_txt, IsReplied, Created_datetime FROM tbl_Enquiry_History WHERE Id =" + enquiry_id.Value.ToString()).Rows[0];
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        Phrase phrase = null;
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        PdfPTable table = null;
        Color color = null;

        document.Open();

        //Header Table
        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.TotalWidth = 500f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 0.7f });

        //Company Logo
        cell = ImageCell("../images/easyweb_logo.gif", 30f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Company Name and Address
        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Electrocom Technology India Limited\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 16, Font.BOLD, Color.RED)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("712, Sukhsagar Complex,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Nr. Hotel Fortune Landmark, Ashram Road,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Ahmedabad - 380 014,", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Gujarat (INDIA).", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Separater Line
        color = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
        DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 79f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 79f, color);
        DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 80f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 80f, color);
        document.Add(table);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 1f });
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

        //Enquiry Detail
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("\n" + "Enquiry Record", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 30f;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        document.Add(table);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.5f, 2f });
        table.TotalWidth = 350f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        //Person Name
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Person Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Person_name"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Company Name
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Company Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Company_name"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Address
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Address :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Address"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //City Name
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("City Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["City_name"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Country Name
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Country Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["CountryName"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //State Name
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("State Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["StateName"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Mobile No
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Mobile No :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Mobile_no"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Phone No
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Phone No :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Phone_no"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Email Address
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Email Address :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Email_address"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Requirement
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Requirement :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Requirement_text"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Reference
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Reference :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Reference_text"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Remarks
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Remarks :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Remarks_txt"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Created Date
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Created Date :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(string.Format("{0:F}", dr["Created_datetime"]) + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        document.Add(table);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.5f, 2f });
        table.TotalWidth = 340f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        if (dr["IsReplied"].ToString()== "True")
        {
            DataRow dr1 = GetData("SELECT [Id],[Title],[Description],[IsFileAttached],[Created_datetime],[TotalFileSize] FROM [FileSystem].[dbo].[tbl_Replies] WHERE Enquiry_History_id = "+ enquiry_id.Value.ToString()+" ORDER BY  Created_datetime DESC").Rows[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < dr1.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //Reply No
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Reply No :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk((i+1).ToString()+ "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.Colspan = 2;
                cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                //Title
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Title :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr1.Table.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.Colspan = 2;
                cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                //Description
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Description :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk((System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(dr1.Table.Rows[i][2].ToString(),@"<(.|\n)*?>",string.Empty)) + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.Colspan = 2;
                cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                //Created Date
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Created Date :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(string.Format("{0:F}", dr1.Table.Rows[i][4]) + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.Colspan = 2;
                cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
                table.AddCell(cell);
                document.Add(table);

                table = new PdfPTable(2);
                table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.5f, 2f });
                table.TotalWidth = 340f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
                table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                if (dr1.Table.Rows[i]["IsFileAttached"].ToString() == "True")
                {
                    DataRow dr2 = GetData("SELECT [File_Title],[File_Size] FROM [FileSystem].[dbo].[tbl_Reply_Files] WHERE Reply_id="+dr1.Table.Rows[i][0].ToString()).Rows[0];
                    table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("File Details :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                    phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk("\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                    table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                    cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    cell.Colspan = 2;
                    cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                    for (int j = 0; j < dr2.Table.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(dr2.Table.Rows[j][0].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr2.Table.Rows[j][1].ToString() + " KB" + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        cell.Colspan = 2;
                        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }
                    table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Total File Size :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                    phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr1.Table.Rows[i][5] + " KB" + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                    table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                    cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    cell.Colspan = 2;
                    cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                    document.Add(table);
                }
            }
        }
        document.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=EnquiryRecord.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        Response.Close();
    }
}
```

how ever this returns improper tabular formate report. Is there i do mistake for placing documnt.Add(table).

this resulted pdf screen shot :

[image]

here j -loop goes wrong and generates two tables...

Comment: You posted 283 lines of code, please try to cut this down to increase your odds of getting help. Also, please describe what "improper tabular format" means, pictures of what you expected and received help, if possible. Lastly, since I see `Color.BLACK` above can I assume you're using 4.1.6? If so, I recommend upgrading to 5.x series since this version is no longer supported.

Comment: i just want to upload picture but it's too long bytes.

Comment: can u just add download link for upgrading new one please.

Comment: iTextSharp most recent binaries can be picked up from http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: @ChrisHaas - i just uploaded one image that gives detail of problem.

Comment: You're going to have to explain specifically what you want changed.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - i just updated question. just see it.

Comment: Sorry @shal, there's really just too much code to run through and your code is tied to your database which we also don't have. I tried replicating a portion but the PDF was fine. However, since the word "File Details" is written twice we know that the problem lives outside of the `j` loop. Start commenting out sections of code and see how much you can get rid of and still have the problem. For instance, get rid of the entire `//Remarks` block and see if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't repeat with another block. Try to get your problem down to 50 lines or so and we might be able to help.